# Retrofit GSON Parsing Arraylist Inside of Object

Tags: java, json, gson, retrofit

I have a json object like this:

```
{
products:[
{
name:Prod1,
quantity:3
},
{
name:Prod2,
quantity:1
}
]
}
```

I have my gson object like so:

```
public class Product{

@SerializedName("name")
public String name;

@SerializedName("quantity")
public int quantity;

}
```

When I set up my retrofit with something like this

```
@GET("/products")
void getProducts(Callback<ArrayList<Product>> c);
```

It will fail, obviously, because that array isn't the root object. Is there a simple way to force this to dig down into the json one level before parsing that ArrayList, or am I going to have to create a whole GSON adapter to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I accomplished this by creating and using my own custom deserializer. The code is simpler than a full Gson Adapter, but accomplishes what I need.

https://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/JsonDeserializer.html